# Is a volatile hashmap sufficient in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

I previously wrote a piece of code which loads classes dynamically from a jar file.
So, basically there can be a.jar in 123-de directory and another a.jar in 456-fg directory. Now depending on certain parameters i decide which jar to use and loads a class say calc.java either from 123-de directory or 456-fg directory.

To do this I had to create classloaders and use these classloaders to load calc.java

Ofcourse there should be a single class loader per jar and single class loaded in memory per class.

To do this I used a concurrent hashmap which stores the class loader/ class.
Say key for this concurrent hashmap is directory name.

So, Given a directory , i check if classloader is already present- if not i create on one then stores it.

```
if(classLoaderMap.get(directoryPath) == null){
        rlock.lock();
        try{
            if(classLoaderMap.get(directoryPath) == null){

                ClassLoader classLoader = // Create classLoader here.
                classLoaderMap.put(directoryPath, classLoader);
            }
        }finally{
            rlock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

This code is tested and is working fine. But today i was revisiting this code and observed that i did not really require concurrenthashmap because i am using explicit locking to write to it. I only need memory visibility because i am reading it outside lock. So, I am really thinking would just `volatile hashmap` had done the job? Should i revert it (Dont want though as it is already tested) OR is it okay if i keep this?

Comment: If you are using java 8, use 'computeIfAbsent' instead of get/get/put. Cleaner code, faster and less chance of getting things wrong (and will be thread safe as well)

Comment: No still at java 6 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not safe to use a regular map, as you would need to lock on both reads and writes. One option is to use a `ReadWriteLock` so you can support non-exclusive reads, while writes remain exclusive to both reads and writes. Another option (probably the better one) is to stick with the `ConcurrentHashMap` and get rid of the lock. As to the question of how to update atomically, just use the atomic `computeIfAbsent()` method:

```
classLoaderMap.computeIfAbsent(directoryPath, p -> /* create class loader */);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this code is on java6 so cannot user computeifabsent. So cannot get rid of the lock :( for now. But wouldn't it be same internally except it will be one lock then? Also, you mentioned locking is required on read, Could you please explain why? I though only memory visibility should work.

Comment: @Ouney: if you don't lock on reads, you'll have memory visibility issues, since the volatile only guarantees the visibility of writes to the classLoaderMap variable itself (i.e. it guarantees you'll se a new map assigned to classLoaderMap), but not changes to the state of the map. And you could also get incoherent values or exceptions, since you'll read from a thread-unsafe data structure while another thread is writing to it and thus modifying it.

Comment: Yeah i got it. I will stick to concurrenthashmap. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Are you accessing the `classLoaderMap` elsewhere to read values from it? If yes, you need to use the same lock there as well to ensure memory visibility.

`volatile` will not help in this case since it will only ensures that updates to the **value** of the variable `classLoaderMap` are visible to other threads, not the contents of the map itself.

I would still recommend using `ConcurrentHashMap` in this case, which then would remove the need for explicit locking and ensure memory visibility of the **contents** of the map.

With Java 8, the code can be simplified a lot more when using `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
classLoaderMap.computeIfAbsent(directoryPath, (path) -> createClassLoader(path));
```

Comment: Even with ConcurrentHashMap i will have to use explicit synchronization because creation of classloader and putting it in ConcurrentHashMap should be atomic.

Comment: @Ouney if you are using Java 8, you can use `computeIfAbsent` to create and store the classloader atomically. See my edit.